# Angular ReactiveForm - form stays valid even after add required (by addValidators) to one formControl

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In my ReactiveForm form, I add required validator to one formControl by condition.

`if(condition) setRequired();`

`setRequired() { this.form.get(['company','id']).addValidators(Validators.required);}`

but form.valid is true, even the field is empty.

Do I need to add something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After remove/add validator to your form element, you have to invoke function with `updateValueAndValidity` to update the state.

Like: `this.form.updateValueAndValidity()`;

Or: `this.form.get(['company','id']).updateValueAndValidity()`;

Comment: it works, but too much...
Because I call the setRequired() from ValueChanges.subscribe - this causes to wake up many times and the app crashes

Comment: you can pass argument to updateValueAndValidity method to stop triggering valuechanges updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent:false})

Comment: @Chellappanவ good answer. And also you can use `distinctUntilChanged()` pipe to prevent recursive subscriptions.